# How to store int data into an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote this simple code to calculate numbers from 1 to 1000 which are multiples of 3 and then store them in an array and then print the array.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    void main(void){

    int i,x,y;
    int A[1000];

    for(i=1;i<1000;i++){
    x=i%3;

    if(x==0){

        A[i]=i;
        printf("%d\n",A[i]);

       }
      }
    }
```

the code is working fine but the thing i wanted to ask is, whether the array will start storing values from A[0] or A[1]? because of the loops counter i=1.

Comment: @haccks: Why is it wrong?

Comment: which part of the code?

Comment: Hint: You initialize the elements of the array only when `(i%3)==0`.

Comment: @gartenriese; Read my answer.

Comment: @haccks: I still don't see where his code is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only place you set the value of an array entry is at:

```
A[i]=i;
```

and i starts at 1 and is not set back in any way, the first entry to be set will of course be `A[1]`.

Comment: So, if i print the array will it contain 0 at A[0] ?

Comment: If you declare the array `static` it will be initialized to all zero - so yes. But otherwise the value of the array is not guaranteed unless you set it - so no. As it is, the only elements that will have a known value are `A[3]`, `A[6]` etc.

Comment: It's unpredictable, you are not initialising it to anything.

Comment: @RahulKhatri, what they said.

Answer (score 1):

Array will start storing values from index 1 as loop start from i=1. 
value at index 0 will remain intact.
but your logic is wrong. if you will print array A[], it will print garbage values
for the array indexes which are not multiple of 3.

Comment: As per your implementation program will not print any garbage value because your are printing indexes only when the index is multiple of 3 so it will not print garbage value.
but it will store values like this.

  A[0]= garbage
  A[1]= garbage
  ..
  A[3]=3
  A[4]= garbage
  ..
  A[6]=6`

Comment: @RahulKhatri - this is exactly why I proposed the slightly different code in my answer - where only "good" values are stored in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You say "the code is working fine". That greatly surprises me.

I am not sure what you want to do with your data, but you might want something like this is you are looking for an array of numbers that are multiples of 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void){  // <<<< int, not void!

    int i,x,y;
    int A[1000];
    y = 0;
    for(i=0;y<1000;i++)  // <<<<< keep looping until array is full, --> test for y not i
    {
      if(i%3 == 0)       // <<<<< no need to assign the result to x
      {
        A[y++]=i;        // fill array only when i%3 == 0; only then increment index count
        printf("Value %d is divisible by 3\n", i);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i was getting the right result thats y i wrote "the code is working fine"